# Add class on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a fixed black filled svg logo in my header that I want to fill white when it scrolls over a dark full width container div further down the page.
This is how the HTML is structured:

```
<header class="header">
    <a href=">
        <svg class="logo__container">
            <g class="logo"></g>
        </svg>
    </a>
</header>
```

```css
.logo__container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}

.logo {
    color: #000000;
}
```

I'm trying to add say `.logo__white` only when the it scrolls over specific divs. Sort of how the logo works here http://www.dtelepathy.com/philosophy/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right u want to add a class to a div when your scroll/page position is on the same point as the start of the div. You can do this with jQuery.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) { // when the page is being scrolled
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); // define current scroll height
    var divHeight = $('.div-name').height(); // define position (height) of the div

    if (scroll > divHeight) { // if the current scroll is higher than the div height
        $('.div-name').addClass('class-name'); // add class name
    }
});
```

*E: Make sure to include jQuery in your project*